# Spliting array with complex regex including empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like `'123,45,6,7'` and want to split it on separate digit: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

I know there is a way to split string by complex regex like this:

`'1 2 3,4a5,6,7'.split(/[^\d]/)` -> `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

Is there way to split this string by regex, something like:

`'123,45,6,7'.split(/[^\d]|empty string/)`?

Comment: `s.match(/\d/g)`?

Comment: you only need to use [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split by positive lookahead with a digit.

```js
console.log('123,45,6,7'.split(/\D|(?=\d)/));
```

Comment: thanks, i found one more way, use global math: '123,45,6,7'.match(/[\d]/g)

Comment: using `'123,45,6,7'.match(/\d/g)` is much less resource intensive than what you are proposing ...

Comment: i know, but the question was about splitting.